# How to create a secure one-user login without using SQL?

Tags: sql, security, authentication

I am planning on creating a little web service to host on my site, but I would like to know how to create a simple, secure login form (username + password) for just one username + password combination, without using SQL. This doesn't have to be super-secure, but it would be nice if you couldn't just crack it by peeking at the source code. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use Basic Auth?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: That looks great, but I'm not sure how I might implement it.

Comment: +1, This is your best approach. @Fin Moorhouse: If your web server is Apache, have a look at this page: http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Comment: @ChristopheD this looks great, and I've already tried a turorial just like this, but I got some funny results. The page does prompt me for the login, but after that all I get is my 404 page- I can't see anything in the directory after I've logged in. I then followed the tutorial you linked to very carefully and the exact same happened- the username/password does not grant access to the directory the htaccess is placed in. Hugely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB). It is a key-value database that is stored in a file. It does not have a server, but it supports concurrent access. Just make sure to put the file outside of where your webserver will serve it (in other words, not next to the CGI script that users are accessing).

Edit: The asker clarified that he wanted something extremely simple to implement with a "limited understanding of web design". In that case, put the username and password in a text file (plain text, JSON, CSV, whatever your programming language can parse the easiest) *in a place where your webserver won't serve it*, and make it readable only by the webserver. You should also [hash the password](http://www.php.net//manual/en/faq.passwords.php) (that link is for PHP, but it will be very similar in other languages).

Comment: As with the other answer, although this looks like it could be a good solution, it is far beyond my limited understanding of web design- thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an OAuth provider (facebook, google, twitter, linked in) and even enable two step verification.

It's really easy to set up, here is an example on PHP using google:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/idtoken.php

And here another using facebook:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/f1916f3a1e8aeece518a18dc88f05775aadb9840/examples/login-logout-get-profile

Both google and facebook have apis for all major languages, but you can also use any standard oauth client if you prefer. Or even implement you own one, the client is actually fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but I just don't know where to start with this, thanks to my clear lack of knowledge. I'll delete the question.

Comment: Just don't be afraid to try and learn. If th hassle with SQL is that you don't want to set up a SQL server and since it's a single login and you don't have to worry about high concurrency you can probably do with SQLite. It's file based and much easier to set up than SQL. Also, remember to hash your passwords using a password hashing function, do not store them in clear! (PHP has the functions password_hash and password_verify to do that, most languages have something similar on their standard libraries...)

Comment: @codedocle thanks for this. I just spent a bit of time looking into htpsswd and htaccess authentications, and it looks like a viable method would be to not let the Apache server list the directory, and then check if a corresponding file exists with the title of the password, but i really ought to look in to sql and its RDBMSs

Comment: HTTP basic auth is remarkably easy to set up since it's already implemented on (almost every) client and server and you just have to deploy it, so it's a really good choice. Anyway, if the hassle with SQL is that you don't want to set up an SQL server and since it's a single login app and you don't have to worry about high concurrency, you can probably do with SQLite. It's much easier to set up than MySQL and can easily be embedded in your app since it doesn't require a server. There are even simpler ways such as using a csv file (most languages implement parsers in their standard libraries)..

Comment: ..but it's not so difficult to figure out the 5 or 6 SQL instructions  you need to set up a proper auth system (`CREATE DATABASE myapp`, `CREATE TABLE myapp.users (userid VARCHAR(255), hashed_password VARCHAR(255))`, `INSERT INTO myapp.users (userid, hashed_password) VALUES ('my_userid','my_hashed_password')`, `SELECT userid, hashed_password FROM myapp.users WHERE userid='myuserid'` and `UPDATE TABLE myapp.users SET hashed_password = 'my_updated_hashed_password' WHERE userid='my_userid'` or `DELETE FROM myapp.users WHERE userid='my_userid'`)...

Comment: ...You can then go further and explore things like indexes and caching to speed up queries and things like that you don't need at all unless you app becomes multi user and really popular :-)

Comment: (Although it's not an effort at all to set `password_hash` and `user_id` to make sure they are not left empty and user_id as a unique index: `CREATE TABLE myapp.users (userid VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL, hashed_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)`)

Comment: elcodedocle im really grateful for this- thanks a lot again. Although i think i understand the very basics of the SQL language, im completely clueless as to how to integrate sql into the wider site. Is the database stored in a certain file format? How do i use the queries in a normal php/html page? I cant seem to find the answers to the most basic question anywhere!

Comment: The database is stored in a file format that depends on the engine. The default engine on mysql is innodb. but the beauty of it is you don't need to worry about that (unless you are an advanced user). The MySQL server is a server listening for MySQL client connections on a port, just like a web server listens for HTTP connections. You app acts as a client connecting to the server and creating/reading/updating/deleting records at your command. Every programming language includes the required client driver and functions to connect to a server and send MySQL queries like the ones I've showed you.

Comment: SQLite uses the same language (SQL) but there is no server. The driver locks the database file, performs the query updating the file accordingly and the unlocks the file. A read lock allows other read locks (but not write) while a write lock doesn't allow access until the lock is released, and all locks are performed automatically by the driver. You just specify the database file and send the queries and that's all you need to worry about.

Comment: Brilliant- does that mean I can use SQLite right inside something like php?

Comment: yes. PHP has 2 different extensions for SQLite (they are usually included on the binary packages, you just have to enable them on php.ini), and you can use any of them (PDO is usually best): http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.sqlite.php http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some kind of server-side scripting? It's not possible in JS.

Since you said it doesn't need to be completely secure, you can basically use hashing and salting to create something which can't be "cracked" by looking at the source. Be aware that if you aren't connecting over https, a malicious users in your local network, ISP, government, etc will able to eavesdrop on the communication and see you transmitting a plain-text password. For this reason alone, **the password shouldn't be re-used anywhere** and **the implications of someone else logging in should be low**.

Here's a crude example of how to generate the hash:

```
<?php
    $salt = "can-be-anything";
    $password = "password";
    $hash = hash_pbkdf2( "sha256", $password, $salt, 1024, 0 );
    echo $hash;
?>
```

and our result is `5b24ad89b5e94c35537f6967b39cf294aa845f94440ebfdd3e857e4cf5f41d7e`. Now you can just follow the same procedure when receiving the password and compare the two hashes. If you reduce the number of iterations it will be easier to brute-force the hash, but will reduce server load.

## Pros

- Can store the hashed password inside the same file
- Someone looking at the source can't learn your password
- Complexity to break the stored password scales with password length

## Cons

- No guarantee of security, someone could eventually gain access
- If not using https, an attacker could learn your password from passive network monitoring

Comment: Thats a great answer- i really just asked this as a bit of a challenge, clearly this is by no means a particularly good idea! This could be the best plan for a single user login with little implications if it's cracked- thanks again

Comment: As a follow up to this, how should i protect the pages in that secure directory from someone who hasn't logges in? For instance, if the login.php goes to welcome.html, how do i stop a random visitor looking at welcome.html and defeating the very reason we are using this?

Comment: @Fin You'll also use server-side scripting. For example you'd use _welcome.php_. Just like most login systems, you can start a session. In PHP you'd use `session_start()` and you can add data, like username to $_SESSION (`$_SESSION["username"] = "Fin"`). Other languages will have something similar. Then you can load that session in _welcome.php_, if your data doesn't exist you can display an error or redirect to a login page. Hopefully I got the formatting of the comment right.